# Trying to understand the blocking nature of WSGI

Tags: python, nginx, concurrency, flask, gunicorn

I have a web app setup like this:

```
nginx <--> gunicorn <--> flask
```

I believe nginx can serve a lot of concurrent connection. But I heard that from the WSGI gateway to the flask app, it's blocking. I.e. only a single request can be served at a time. I read it [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html). My question is: why couldn't nginx invoke another instance (not sure if this is the right term) of gunicorn and handle multiple request in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply not true, Gunicorn (and all other WSGI app servers) can (and should) be configured to use multiple threads, processes, or eventlets depending on the specific WSGI server's concurrency model.  Each thread (or eventlet) in each process dispatches one request at a time to the app it is running.

Nginx does nothing to launch the first, or any subsequent, WSGI processes.  You start the WSGI server, configured correctly, and it handles the concurrency.  Nginx dispatches requests as concurrently as it can to whatever app it is configured to proxy to.